# spring batch how to import multiple files with foreign key

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I'm using Spring Batch to import some old data into my new database. I already exported each table to different csv/excel file.

For instance, `account.xlsx` has `userInfoId`,`accountName` and `password`.
`userinfo.xlsx` has `id`, `name`, `age` and `contact`.

But how to concatenate or read multiple files with mapping to get the foreign key relationship from these records. I need to create new user entity with both info in these two files, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the foreign key info is actually IN the files.

Notwithstanding the THRICE DAMNED XML based declaration [THIS](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-batch/spring-batch-multiresourceitemreader-example/) seems to be what you are trying to do.  The key is the MultiResourceItemReader.

Edit: You will almost certainly need an ItemProcessor of course.

Comment: If I understand correct, MultiResourceItemReader can only handle multiple files with same record structure, like an info table separated into multiple files, not multiple files with different record structure (in my case, account and userinfo have different structure).

Comment: Hmm. Good point!  Maybe back to my first idea I was going to propose of using multiple job Steps?

Comment: How to achieve this from different step?

Comment: What is the schema?  And what are the keys?  It seems you could use one step to create the parent table and then another step to create the child table and update the foreign key.  You can absolutely put Spring Data calls in your ItemProcessor, I’ve done that.